# Proper use of AngularJS' $sanitize service?

Tags: javascript, security, angularjs, sanitization

Not so long ago, I came across a tutorial about authentication in AngularJS. They created an `AuthenticationService` that looked kind of like this:

```
angular.module("auth").factory("AuthenticationService", function ($http, $sanitize) {

    function sanitizeCredentials(credentials) {
        return {
            username: $sanitize(credentials.username),
            password: $sanitize(credentials.password)
        };
    }

    return {
        login: function (credentials) {
            return $http.post("auth/login", sanitizeCredentials(credentials));
        }
    };
});
```

So as you see, the `$sanitize` service is used to sanitize the username as well as the password. So far so good, but does it really make sense to use it here? As far as I know, `$sanitize` is used when user input is immediately displayed inside html. But when I send something to the server is it really useful to sanitize it on the frontend? Since anyone can  override this part, I would need to do this on the server again anyway. So why not just send it un-sanitized and do the important stuff on the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to have two parts.

Regarding `$sanitize` when immediately displayed, not sure what this means, b/c you'll likely have `ng-model` to capture the username.

Regarding sending a sanitized username / passwd from the client rather than doing it on the server, it's a reasonable question. Technically you could do either. IMO it's a matter of keeping user inputs clean at all times from the pov of your code. All inputs should be sanity checked at the earliest point. Critical pieces like credentials should have two layers of sanity, lest one inadvertently disappear. Or worse, an attack vector is discovered in one of your two (or more) sanity layers.

Recall a well-known ldap attack vector where a username reads like `im-a-user)&&()`. The close parens followed by an and null is an exploit. Why have such strings floating around when they could be scrubbed at the point of input?